# Memory leak - SQLCommand object?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, memory-leaks

Please have a look at the code below, which I have written as a test.  It does not make the ASP.NET process grow too much:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try

            Dim Test As Integer

            For Test = 0 To 1000000
                Test1()
            Next
            Dim Test2 As String = "Test"
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub Test1()
        Try

            Dim objCommand As New SqlCommand
            Dim strConString As String = "Data Source=IANSCOMPUTER;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"
            Dim objCon As New SqlConnection
            objCon.ConnectionString = strConString
            objCon.Open()
            objCommand.Connection = objCon
            objCommand.CommandText = "select * from person "
            Dim objDR As SqlDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader
            If objDR.HasRows Then
                Using objCon

                End Using
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
          'I don't swallow exceptions. 
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am trying to detect a memory leak.  I have found code similar to the above in the affected project.  I notice that objCommand.dispose is not called.  The project in question connects to an Oracle database and an SQL database.  When connecting to an SQL database the above code is used.  When connecting to an Oracle database Oracle.dataaccess.dll is used and the code looks different to reflect this.

My specific question is: if I avoid calling sqlcommand.dispose then will this cause a memory leak over time?

Comment: If objRdr.HasRows is False, you will not be closing objCon. As you are using Try..Catch you need to make sure you close the SqlConnection in the Finally section. And why are you naming almost everything obj<Name>? And strConString is getting silly ;)

Comment: @Andrew Morton, thanks.  For the purpose of this test I can confirm that objDR.HasRows will always return true.

Answer (score 1):

If a class has a Dispose method, that isn't getting called, then it is likely to be the source of a memory leak.  Use Using, and it will call the Dispose method for you.

Your second example should look like the below, where all disposable object are wrapped in using blocks.

```
Dim strConString As String = "Data Source=IANSCOMPUTER;" +
                              "Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"
Dim sqlStr as String = "select * from person "
Using objCon As New SqlConnection(strConString)
    Using objCommand As New SqlCommand(sqlStr, objCon)
        objCon.Open()
        Using objDR As SqlDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader
            If objDR.HasRows Then
            End If
        End Using
     End Using
End Using
```

Comment: MSDN seems to support your arguement.  Can you explain why the code I have provided does not seem to cause a memory leak? Thanks.

Comment: I would guess that it does, it's just not showing up in your test.